# TabLayout gone up when virtual Keyboard is opened. Need TablLayout to be Hidden and The Entry form should be fully Scrollable to last Field

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-keypad

Tab layout going up when virtual keyboard is opened.

Please check the Screenshot attached.

The Entry form is placed inside as a row of Recyclerview.and this recyclerview is inside a Fragment.Tab layout is in the Activity.

1.Given in Manifest for Activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

[image]

2.when used in another way as

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

[image]

one Edittext and one Button is available on the form after Local Price Field it cannot be viewed by scrolling.

3.when given as

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

it is working as   `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Did you add `scrollView`?

Comment: @SamirBhatt sorry,Question Title updated.

Comment: @tahsinRupam the Entry form is already in a RecyclerView. in this app  we have multiple Entry adding provision.

Comment: @SamirBhatt please help

Comment: @tahsinRupam please help

Comment: As per my understanding, you need to make tablayout at bottom and content should be above keyboard. Right?

Comment: @SamirBhatt  yes.and the content should be fully scrollable when  keyboard is open.

Comment: That is not logical proper way. As you can understand, android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" resizes screen as per keyboard's height. So, It will make content scrollable automatically, So, if you want to make content scrollable, you have to resize view that will also make tablayout above the keyboard. You can make the patch by dynamic blank space below your content when you open keyboard with adjustpan. but this is not the prefreable way.

Comment: @SamirBhatt , i could not hide it by this way!!